# The simpliest way to change only colors in theme

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, colors, themes

I'm using WPF Toolkit Themes( http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes ).
Actually I'm using only ExpressionDark.

But I want to change colors for every control. Need I override all elements and write whole of the big code? Isnt there any siplier way to change only colors? I need only change hue. Isnt there any applications, addons or so on which can change the hue in every colors in this theme?

Comment: I was looking for a way to use a single base-color that could be "inherited" by other colors, and found this. It could be an option if you want to pay for it
http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/kiril_matev/archive/2010/08/30/theming-your-infragistics-wpf-line-of-business-applications-made-quick-and-easy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any addons, but usually I'd put all my Colors in a separate XAML file so I can swap out that resource dictionary as needed

For example:

```
<Color x:Key="BorderColor_Base">#FF8DB2E3</Color>
<Color x:Key="BackgroundColor_Base">White</Color>
<Color x:Key="BorderBrushDark">#FF8DB2E3</Color>
<Color x:Key="BorderBrushLight">#FFC0F9FF</Color>
```

You can also overwrite System colors, using syntax such as:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
```

Comment: Actully I want to change colors for existing template not defining my own colors palette. But how can I cange colors for default controls without editing thier template? I tried to do it overriding SystemColors but actually not every colors in controls have been changed.

Comment: @nosbor What syntax did you use for overridding `SystemColors`? I added the syntax I use to do such things in my answer. If that doesn't work then it's possible that whatever default style you're using has some colors hard-coded in.

Comment: Exactly the same syntax as you. I tried to replace all of these http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms603159.aspx SystemColors to orange and expected to see ogrange screen. But for eg. Button background wasnt orange. I saw also that some colors make application throwing exception. Try to override these colors: ControlTextColor, DesktopColor, HighlightTextColor, InfoTextColor, MenuBarColor, MenuColor, MenuHighlightColor, MenuTextColor, WindowColor, WindowTextColor

Comment: Here is a package of colors that you dont need to it on your self: http://www.speedyshare.com/files/30586100/SystemColors.zip